# How do I deal with multiple word keyphrases and exact search in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, indexing

### How do I deal with multiple word keyphrases and exact search in Solr?

Hi. I need some help on the following issue:

I am indexing a list of shops of which each shop has a list of productwords that contain single keyword keyphrases like 'bike' and multiple keyword keyphrases like 'red bike'.

Example: Store A sells 'ipad' and 'iphone'. Store B sells 'ipad accessoires' and 'iphone', Store C sells 'ipad' and 'ipad accessoires'

When a user performs a search for 'ipad' I want only the stores that have a exact match on 'ipad' (i.e. only store A and C) to show up in the results.

In my current solr setup a keyphrase like 'ipad accessoires' gets tokenized to 'ipad' and 'accessoires' and when a user searches for 'ipad' store B shows up as well. How do I get a keyphrase like 'ipad accessoires' in the index with solr understanding it's actually 1 keyphrase/token to match upon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two things we've been thinking about:

a) replace spaces with a tilde (~) sign, both at the index as well as the query side. e.g. 'ipad accessoires' becomes 'ipad~accessoires'

b) remove the spaces of multiple word keyphrases so that they become one word (again; both at index as well as query side): e.g. 'ipad accessoires' becomes 'ipadaccessoires'

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to try something different check upon [Percolate](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/percolate.html) Query in Elastic Search.
This is probably exactly what you are trying to do a reverse matching somthing link Google adwords.